# Boot files get compressed in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot

Today when i press power button of my computer. after bios startup no windows logo was shown but some lines were there "TFGHT" is compressed press ctrl+alt+del to restart. I press the buttons more than 5 times but nothing happen except restarting. About one year ago I also confront with the same problem. i know the reason about that problem that is i was low on HDD space so i saw an option in the properties of the disk C where the operating system was installed "compress this drive to save disk space. after starting that process  cancelled that process in the middle because it is taking so much of time. at that time i have the bootable flashdrive of windows 7. but this time i dont have that one but i have the system repair disk that have some tools to repair windows like startup repair,CMD etc

Can i fix the problem with that disk if yes then with tool should i use. If not then what should i do ? buy new windows and install it? any another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compressed the entire drive to save space and now the system will not boot with the compressed boot manager error.

Boot from a Vista or W7 DVD, when "Install Windows"  loads select "Next" and then "Repair My computer", if you get a message "Windows has found problems with your Computer's Startup Options" and offers you two options, "Repair and Restart" or "No". If this happens, click on NO.

Click on "Load Drivers" , then "OK" a window will open, on the left side click "Computer" icon, right click on your C drive (or where ever the OS is installed) and select properties, if the "Compress this drive to save disk space" is checked, Un Check it and hit Hit apply, and apply to subfolders/files., it will take some time to uncompress the drive, be patient.

If the compress this drive is not checked, check it then uncheck it to get the apply button to activate.

When De-compressing is done Cancel all remaining windows until only the System Recovery Options dialog box is left open and click on Next. Click on Restart and Vista-W7 should load.

*Note: if you were low on disk space when you compressed the drive you may need to make room by deleting or copying some files off of the drive before you de-compress the entire drive.*

**Alternatively** you can load the command prompt after you select "Repair Your Computer" then run these 2 commands (hit enter after each command, spaces are important) to decompress just the boot manager. This is a faster solution to get it booting and leaves the rest of the files compressed, which removes the need to make room on the disk to get it booting again.

> compact /U C:\bootmgr
>
> compact /U C:\ntldr

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your OS cannot boot due to part but not all of the OS files being compressed.  The only solutions I can think of are to run the windows repair from the setup disk, restore an earlier version if you have system protection enabled, or remove the drive, install it in another computer and decompress the drive.

Outside of those options You may need to reinstall Windows.  If you have enough disk space, you can do this over the previous version and retain your documents/data.

Consider purchasing an external hard disk for data storage, or uploading files to cloud networks such as Microsoft's One Drive to reduce used disk space.